# I have a fb app. I want to get the webbook response to my app, whenever a user tags a particular page (of another user). how to do this?

Tags: web, oauth, access-token, user-permissions

I have a fb app. I want to get the webbook response to my app, whenever a particular page(of some other user) is tagged. How to do this? What permission do i need to take from the page?
Is there some other way to do that also get any kind of response to the app, whenever a particular page is tagged?

Comment: You should always use objective quesetions in your posts and also offer some code that you tried to make work. SO is not a website where others offers code based on your request, but a site that help you make your code works.

Comment: I just want to know that what permissions i need to do sp